Regular expression isn't matching all hyperlinks in a string
I have some text:
const str = `This <a href="https://regex101.com/" data-link-id="431ebea7-1426-65a5-8383-55a27313dc51">is a test link</a> which has a hyperlink, and <a href="https://regex102.com/" data-link-id="d62dc3eb-7b3d-953e-4d7a-987448e6928d">this is also</a> a hyperlink.`

I'm trying to match all a tags, but my regular expression just returns the whole thing:
str.match(/<a href=".+ data-link-id="[0-9A-Z-a-z]{1,}">(.*?)<\/a>/)

What am I doing wrong here? I expect the result to be an array of two elements. Instead of (.*?), I've tried .+ and [A-Za-z0-9\s]+, same result.

The issue isn't with (.*?) - it's with the href=".+ which matches until the second tag. With that said - why not use DOM parsing that will extract the data without any complications?

Because I'm using a contentEditable div in lieu of a text area (where a user can highlight text and dynamically create hyperlinks inside it). Therefore I'm restricted to having access only to a stringified DOM structure

"Therefore I'm restricted to having access only to a stringified DOM structure" - why? The contentEditable element is part of the DOM same as everything else, and so are its children.

@CBroe Moreover, parsing DOM is not even reliant on a contenteditable or not.

Your current regex pattern has one slight bug in it, which is that it uses href=.+  as part of matching the anchor tag.  The .+ is problematical because it is greedy, and will match across all anchors until the last one.  If you instead use .+? it will behave as you want.


var str = 'This <a href="https://regex101.com/" data-link-id="431ebea7-1426-65a5-8383-55a27313dc51">is a test link</a> which has a hyperlink, and <a href="https://regex102.com/" data-link-id="d62dc3eb-7b3d-953e-4d7a-987448e6928d">this is also</a> a hyperlink.';
var matches = str.match(/<a href=".+? data-link-id="[0-9A-Z-a-z]{1,}">(.*?)<\/a>/g);
console.log(matches);



Note also that you should use the global /g flag with match() to get all matches.

Wow, thank you, I've been pulling my hair out for well over an hour

@MikeK I pulled my hair out for about 10 minutes, then gave up, and moved your problem to a regex tool: https://regex101.com/r/rPlw89/1 ... it was clear from there what the behavior was.

As a further suggestion, if you intend to solve exactly that scenario, it would be better dealing with an actual HTML parser instead of using regular expressions since html may have nested elements or special content embedded that wouldn't be possible to obtain using regex.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString

The parseFromString() method of the DOMParser interface parses a
string containing either HTML or XML, returning an HTMLDocument or an
XMLDocument.



const str = `This <a href="https://regex101.com/" data-link-id="431ebea7-1426-65a5-8383-55a27313dc51">is a test link</a> which has a hyperlink, and <a href="https://regex102.com/" data-link-id="d62dc3eb-7b3d-953e-4d7a-987448e6928d">this is also</a> a hyperlink.`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const anchors = doc.querySelectorAll('a');

console.log(anchors);



